# Skip already categorized mails

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, outlook-filter

Current Code:

```
Dim outlookapp
Dim olns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Object

'Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myTasks
Dim projIDsearch As String
Dim myrecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim daysAgo As Long

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olns = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myrecipient = olns.CreateRecipient("Ccbcphelpdesk")
myrecipient.Resolve

'Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ExemptionReview")
Set Fldr = olns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myrecipient, olFolderInbox)
' Restrict search to daysAgo
daysAgo = 0
Set myTasks = Fldr.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format(Date - daysAgo, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'")
projIDsearch = ActiveCell.Cells(1, 4)

For Each olMail In myTasks
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, projIDsearch, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        olMail.Categories = "ESP"
        olMail.Save
    End If
Next
end sub
```

This looks up emails pertaining to a search string in the subject then tags them as ESP. I need to skip emails that are already categorized.

I have tried:

```
If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, projIDsearch, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
    If olmail.categories Is nothing then 'line returns and error 424
        olMail.Categories = "ESP"
        olMail.Save
    End If
End If
```

How can I skip **Emails that are already categorized and only categorize emails with no category?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860423.aspx

`Categories` is a String-type property, so test with something like:

```
If Len(olmail.Categories) = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Logical Operators **`And Not`** on your *[Restrict method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx)*

```
Set myTasks = Fldr.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format(Date - daysAgo, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "' And Not [Categories] = 'ESP'")
```

and remove your `If olmail.categories Is nothing` that way your not checking every `olmail`- and it should speedup your loop